# How to execute custom javascript or external js in AMP page on page load?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amp-html

I want to add integrate chatbot like "https://plan-your-trip.user.com/login/?next=/" to my mobile amp page. And what this js to execute on page load.
I have tried amp-script - but it works with some user interaction. I want JS to execute on page load.

Sample Chat bot script:
https://user.com/en/integrations/custom-script/

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look [amp-iframe](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-iframe/?format=websites), which will allow you to load your chat bot in an iframe.